# Uniqueness of a particular linear application

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Prove there is a unique linear application $W \to W$ such that:

1. $f(1,-1,1,-1)=(1,-1,-1,1)$
2. $f(f(v))=0$ $\forall v \in W$

My attempt: If the application is unique, then there is a unique matrice such that

1. $A(1,-1,1,-1)=(1,-1,-1,1)$
2. $A(AX)=0 \implies (AA)X=0 \implies A^2=0$

Then we must find a matrix such that $$A(1,-1,1,-1)=(1,-1,-1,1) \\A^2=0$$
But I'm stuck here, any suggestions?

Comment: Apply the second equality to the first. What do you get?

Comment: @Al.G. A^3 (1,-1,1,-1)=A^2(1,-1,-1,1) ?

Comment: I mean, act with $A$ on the first equality.

Comment: A(A)(X)=A(1,-1,-1,1) -> A^2(X)=A(1,-1,-1,1) ?

Comment: yours is probably a suggestion to demonstrate uniqueness, but is it possible to determine the matrice?

Comment: Yes. Now apply $A^2=0$ to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149856/discussion-between-al-g-and-afraidguy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim isn't true---there's more than one such linear transformation. In fact, some such linear transformations have rank $1$ and others rank $2$, so there isn't even a unique solution up to, e.g., conjugacy.

**Hint** Since a linear transformation $T$ is determined by what it does to a basis, so it's enough to pick a basis ${\mathcal B} := ({\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2, {\bf v}_3, {\bf v}_4)$ of $W$ and express each $T({\bf v}_i)$ as a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal B$. In particular, we need not construct and explicit matrix (though we could explicitly construct many matrices from the below considerations).

It's natural to work in a basis that contains the vectors singled out by condition (1), say, take $${\bf v}_1 := (1, -1, -1, 1)^\top \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad {\bf v}_2 := (1, -1, 1, -1)^\top .$$ (We can choose both of these vectors to be in our basis because $\{{\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2\}$ is linearly independent.) Then, condition (1) is simply that $T({\bf v}_2) = {\bf v}_1$.

What can you say about $T({\bf v_1})$? And then $T({\bf v}_3)$ and $T({\bf v}_4)$?